# Route to Current User Edit in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the syntax I need to use in order to route to edit the current user's profile? I want to put a link on my page that takes you to edit your user profile. I know how to link_to but not sure what what the syntax is to get to the current user.

```
<%= link_to "Edit Profile", current_user %>
```

My `UsersController` looks like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy


  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
        flash[:notice] = "Welcome to Studio Academy Manager"
      sign_in @user
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name, :phone, :street_1, :street_2, :city, :state, :zip, :enabled, :admin)
  end

  def logged_in_user
  unless current_user.present?
      store_location
      flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end

  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user
  end

  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

And In my routes file I have:

```
  resources :users
```

Comment: How are you storing the current user's information? I'm guessing you're storing some kind of information in their session like their user id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as:

```
link_to 'Edit profile', [:edit, current_user]
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks man I couldn't figure out that syntex for the life of me haha

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the brackets notation

```
link_to 'Edit profile', [:edit, current_user]
```

or the [named routes helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers), which you get by invoking `rake routes`

```
link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_path(current_user)
```